# Deploying one smart contract to two blockchains (ethereum and polygon)

Tags: blockchain, openzeppelin, polygon, opensea

I am thinking to deploy one smart contract to two blockchains(polygon and ethereum) because I want the minter to be able to select a blockchain on my website. What will happen to the collection on OpenSea? Will it appear in one collection? (Opensea used to do this by default, I want to do the same via smart contract)

Will OpenSea auto rename the collection with “V2”?

Answer (score 1):

You're going in the right direction by having 2 contracts deployed on each mainnet. (Ethereum and Polygon (MATIC))

Have you read up on Polygon's Bridging techniques?

You'll have to carefully craft each contract to allow minting from Ethereum's mainnet or Polygon's MATIC mainnet. (This is due to NFTs basic core concepts of being non-fungible).

This may not be done without some centralized service checking for events and dispatching more tx on the opposing chain. [OpenZeppelin's Defender](https://openzeppelin.com/defender/) service can do this with minimal code. Perhaps there is a crafty way to do this in Solidity, but I'm not currently aware of this pattern.

**Or** you could choose a default blockchain to mint from.
Then allow bridging to the other chain.
This would be much easier to do if your timeline is in a crunch.

Here's some links that you'll find useful:

- [Getting Started](https://docs.polygon.technology/docs/develop/ethereum-polygon/getting-started)
- [NFT Bridge](https://medium.com/@polygoncommunitychannel/polygon-bridge-for-matic-eth-nft-f75c6e0d6020)
- [How to use the Polygon
  Bridge](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/how-to-use-the-polygon-bridge)

Comment: Bridging is to transfer token from one blockchain to another correct? What if I will keep NFT on its own blockchain.. however is it possible to have those NFTs (from ethereum and polygon) to appear in one collection on OpenSea? (same as opensea used to do by default) . What I’m thinking is if the contracts have the same name it will be on one collection? hmm

Comment: That's correct!
I believe, based on the behavior I've personally observed and from lack of documentation on OS (OpenSea), that you cannot currently have 1 collection page on OS that's backed by 2 different chains (Ethereum & Polygon). 
Each collection needs a unique name (for the URL) and a smart contract address paired with which chain the smart contract address is deployed to. 
So 1 collection that's bridged by 2 chains would show up as 2 collections on OS. I would open a support ticket with OS and ask if they have plans to develop future support for this scenario.